# Android Studio - No option to Link C++ to Gradle

Tags: android, c++, android-studio, cmake, android-gradle-plugin

I have been trying to access some CPP Libraries from android and have been following the instructions here:

https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#link-gradle

The issue is that there doesn't seem to be an option to 'Link C++ Project with Gradle' when I right click on the app module. Has anyone else had this issue? Did you solve it?

Answer (score 25):

Check in your build.gradle file for your App's module. Mine looked like this from the default Android Project:

```
externalNativeBuild {
        cmake {
            path "CMakeLists.txt"
        }
    }
```

I removed the cmake section and resynced the project and then the "Link C++ Project with Gradle" was finally available as an option.

Comment: This is indeed the root cause

Comment: I use NdkBuild, not cmake

Comment: After I added `externalNativeBuild {}`, it showed up. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Look for a file called "build.gradle"( Module: app ) in "Gradle Scripts" folder.

```
 defaultConfig {
 ...
 }
 buildTypes {
 ...
 }
```

Add:

```
externalNativeBuild {

}
```

Save and Sync Now

Then right click on "app" and you will see "**Link C++ Project with Gradle**"

Comment: Should it still work? It doesn't show up in Android Studio 4.1.2. Has anything changed?